# How to change default list path of AVD manager in linux?

Tags: android

I do read relevant topics before asking the question, but none is helpful.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, the default path of AVD is ~/.android/avd, and I would like to change it, how can I make it?

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a symbolic link to change the default path of AVD in Linux.

```
mv ~/.android/avd ~/.android/avd_bak #take backup of existing images in case you need them
ln -s path/to/my/avd ~/.android/avd
```

Now whenever you create a new image they will actually be created in the new location. For moving the existing images to the new folder you can follow the steps mentioned in [Rajesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10846668/80313)

Comment: oh the beauty of Linux. What an elegant solution :)

Comment: work perfect.. i have a m2 disk and my space was reduced by instalation android.. work like charm

Answer (score 8):

From Android Developer Guide [Managing AVDs from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html) where the following is stated:

> **Default location of AVD files**
>
> When you create an AVD, the android tool creates a dedicated directory for it on your development computer. The directory contains the AVD configuration file, the user data image and SD card image (if available), and any other files associated with the device. Note that the directory does not contain a system image — instead, the AVD configuration file contains a mapping to the system image, which it loads when the AVD is launched.
>
> The `android` tool also creates an `<AVD_name>.ini` file for the AVD at the root of the .android/avd/ directory on your computer. The file specifies the location of the AVD directory and always remains at the root the .android directory.
>
> By default, the `android` tool creates the AVD directory inside `~/.android/avd/` (on Linux/Mac), `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\` on Windows XP, and `C:\Users\<user>\.android\` on Windows 7 and Vista. If you want to use a custom location for the AVD directory, you can do so by using the `-p <path>` option when you create the AVD:

```
android create avd -n my_android1.5 -t 2 -p path/to/my/avd
```

> If the .android directory is hosted on a network drive, we recommend using the -p option to place the AVD directory in another location. The AVD's .ini file remains in the .android directory on the network drive, regardless of the location of the AVD directory.

It should be clear that new AVDs can be created on different location by using the `-p <path>` option. If you want to move the existing AVDs, you should edit the corresponding `.ini` files and alter the `path=` attribute, while making sure that you leave the `.ini` files in the `~/.android/avd` directory. (Just to be safe, make sure you take a backup of the `.ini` files before you tamper with them)

Comment: Thanks, I had read this quide, but is there any way to change the default location permanently?

Comment: I guess not, because the Android SDK & tools do not use any system registry/configuration values.

Answer (score 4):

"I guess not, because the Android SDK & tools do not use any system registry/configuration values."
Also there doesn't seem to be a setting available to enter the path. What a disgrace. It is a disgrace because it is hard coded.

Quick-fix for those win 7 users who were so adventures that upgraded to a colour monitor as against the linux-standard green/amber screen and now dare to look down on command line:

From \Users\ directory copy the .android directory into the C:\Users\ directory.

Apart from the avd directory the rest can be deleted.
Inside the avd directory the yourdevice.avd directory is not necessary.
All you need is the .ini file.
There is also no need to modify the path inside the .ini file either. It points to the right location.

When you create a new device-profile, it is saved to the NORMAL path IE: as before:
\Users\.android\avd
Copy and paste the device's .ini file from \Users\.android\avd directory to the C:\Users\.android\avd directory.

I did some testing, it seems to work.
If there is a problem with this approach, please tell about it.

May I ask the Android SDK developers to do a search for "Microsoft Windows Operating System", for "Graphical User Interface" and for "hardcoding" as it relates to programming practices.

Comment: Just going to point out that this does not in fact answer the question of the asker, as the asker is running a Linux system. Additionally, this answer is downright dismissive of linux - "the linux-standard green/amber screen". Also, it goes on a tirade against the android SDK writers instead of answering the linux question.